# c# Telegram.Bot v17.0.0

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

в старых версиях Telegram.Bot были методы `client.StartReceiving` и `StopReceiving`. В последней версии их нет, как принимать запросы?

Comment: ([ссылка](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)) _Polling inside the library is now considered obsolete. The code, related to polling will be removed. It is recommended to use [Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling) package instead. These methods are now obsolete: `StartReceiving`, `StopReceiving`._

Answer (score 0):

Тебе надо скачать пакет "Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling", а пакет "Telegram.Bot" удалить.
(Мне помогло)